# List categories alphabetically in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

Is there any way to list all categories in WordPress in a dictionary fashion:

A

cat.

cat.

cat.

B

cat.

cat.

cat.

C

cat.

cat.

cat.

...and so on

I thank you in advance

Comment: All categories of what? Pages, posts, tags?

Comment: You really should use Google, came out as top hit in the Wordpress Codex... 'wp_list_categories'

Comment: This question would be better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

if you know some php you can modify or create a category.php page in your themes main directory. Then simply add the following lines to make it alphabetical:

```html
<?php
get_header();
?>

<div id="content">
<ul>
<?php
// we add this, to show all posts in our
// Glossary sorted alphabetically
if (is_category('Glossary')) 
{
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
$glossaryposts = get_posts( $args ); 
}
foreach( $glossaryposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 
 ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Toni, glad it helped, which answer worked for you? I see your new here, if you could click on the up arrow or the check mark on the answer(s) that helped you, that would help me out cause I wrote both answers. But generally if you get a good answer you should vote it up or click the check mark to select the best answer for you. And that would give the person that answered more reputation points and more privileges. Like for me I only need 2 more reputation points and then I'll be able to comment on peoples questions. So if you come across my message I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't know php and want a plugin for it, this simple one here should work to alphabetize categories, posts and pages:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-alphabetical-post-listing/
though I have not tried it myself, so let me know if it works.